# How to span mulitiple tables with a view, when the tables have same structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

So we have a db that receives constant input and then we have it moved after x days to a different db as a type of archive/reporting db. So the question is when I try to create a view that combines two of the tables (one from each db):

`CREATE VIEW Table_Full AS
 SELECT *
 FROM [Front].dbo.[DATA] AS A
 Inner Join Back.dbo.DATA AS B
 ON A.DATETIME=B.DATETIME`

I get the following error: "Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'PARTNO' in view or function 'Table_Full' is specified more than once."

So, is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do or ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your use case, I think you want a union. That is

```
select * from table_a
Union all
Select * from table_b
```

Comment: I believe this is a better solution for what I am trying to accomplish!

Comment: If you found the solution helpful, give it an upvote and/or mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an asterisk, you have to specify each field and provide aliases for the duplicate field names:

```
CREATE VIEW Table_Full AS
 SELECT  
   a.ID as A_ID,
   b.ID as B_ID,
   a.Thingy as A_Thingy,
   a.Etcetera as Atcetera
 FROM [Front].dbo.[DATA] AS A
 Inner Join Back.dbo.DATA AS B
 ON A.DATETIME=B.DATETIME
```